# JsSIP How to detect call transfer successfullly

Tags: javascript, typescript, webrtc, phone-call, jssip

A holding session with B and calling on session with C. A transfer B to C by implementing code below. How to get info of B in C, i tried listening `ua.on('newMessage', cb)` and adding `ua.sendMessage(currentSession?.remote_identity.uri, 'dataOfB')` in A but `ua.on('newMessage', cb)` only fired in A.
How to C detect call transfered successfully or get message from A. Thanks all!

```
    replaces: currentSession,
    mediaConstraints: { audio: true, video: false },
     pcConfig: {
     rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate',
    },
  };
  holdSession?.refer(currentSession?.remote_identity.uri, options);
  currentSession?.terminate();
  holdSession?.terminate();
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their [docs](https://jssip.net/documentation/3.9.x/api/session/#method_refer):

> A REFER method implicitly generates a subscription to the state of the
> refer. The NOTIFY requests received from the peer are processed and
> presented in form of events by JsSIP.RTCSession.ReferSubscriber.

The documentation on these events can be found [here](https://jssip.net/documentation/3.9.x/api/refer_subscriber/).

Take a look at this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66784763/15595594) for a working example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).